# What does "pinch it off" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> LIVERPOOL 0-0 MAN CITY
>
> 21: SAVE! Bernardo **pinches it off** Henderson and after a wonderful mazy run, he puts through Foden and he only has Alisson to beat but the Liverpool stopper spreads himself well to make a crucial save. What play from Silva!

What does "pinches it off" mean in the highlighted sentence?

Comment: The vocabulary of sports reporting is very specialized. Consider “up a set and a break.”

Comment: Too specialized for this site.

Comment: Not specialized at all.  It's not Sports terminology. It's   perfectly normal British slang. The same word could be used in any other situations.

Answer (score 4):

Here the word *pinch* is used with the meaning of *steal*.

**Pinch**
Transitive verb (informal)
*to steal something*

[Cambridge: Pinch](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pinch)

So **pinches it off**, in this context, is used to mean *steals it off* (or *from*).

Since this is a football match, it's not a literal case of theft but Bernardo simply tackling the ball away from the other player, Henderson.